# every usb flash drives manufactured by any company have unique serial key or not?

Tags: usb, key, serial-number, usb-flash-drive

I would like to know, if every usb flash drives manufactured by any company have unique serial key or not? If yes, can we retrieve it using any programming languages.

Comment: but i found the interfacedescriptor has an unique id. Look http://usb4java.org/apidocs/org/usb4java/InterfaceDescriptor.html

Answer (score 1):

No. Serial numbers are optional on USB drives. Some manufacturers use them, others do not.